# Can I call a scaler for transformations when using columnTransformer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've scaled a dataset and it's been working fine but I want to quickly scale new data entries without having to rescale the existing data as I do not want the existing scaling to change. Is there a way to know the scaled value of a dataset based on existing scaler?

If I was using just a standard scaler, this is how I would achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
dfTest = pd.DataFrame({'A':[14.00,90.20,90.95,96.27,91.21]})
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(dfTest)
print(scaled)
[[-1.99528969]
 [ 0.43635594]
 [ 0.46028946]
 [ 0.63005789]
 [ 0.46858641]]
print(scaler.transform([[90.0]]))
[[0.42997366]]
```

This is what I'm trying to do but I'm using columnTransformer(like below) and I'm not sure how to access the standard scaler like I did above to pass a variable to it `scaler.transform([[90.0]]`

```
data_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([('standard_scaler', StandardScaler(), ["A"])],sparse_threshold=0)
total_x=data_pipeline.fit_transform(dfTest)
```

above works but I have no idea how to call the standard_scaler from columnTranformer.

Is there anything I can do to directly access the standard scaler for transformations?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Create a dataframe with the same column name and then pass it to the transform function for the columtransformer:

```
data_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([('standard_scaler', StandardScaler(), ["A"])],sparse_threshold=0)
total_x=data_pipeline.fit_transform(dfTest)
print(total_x)
[[-1.99528969]
 [ 0.43635594]
 [ 0.46028946]
 [ 0.63005789]
 [ 0.46858641]]
dfRandom = pd.DataFrame({'A':[90.20]})
print(data_pipeline.transform(dfRandom))
[[0.43635594]]
```